# How do I add Mac OS X 10.6.6 Update to my Mac OS X 10.6.3 dmg

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

I want to make a bootable dmg that already includes the 10.6.6 update in it. And when I will install the OS will be 10.6.6.
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: How is this programming-related ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](http://www.lanrev.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=582&sid=04640062eb4dd6cab46ba00f765ad3d2), it covers this process in great detail.